# unkown error when writing sql table from R

Tags: r, sql-server, function, rodbc, ff

To print a sql table in SQL Server I wrote the following function:

```
writeTableSql <- function(table, dat, tablename){
#libraries
 library(RODBC)
 library(ETLUtils)
 library(ff)
 dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) if (is.character(x)) as.factor(x) else 
  {x})
 ETLUtils::write.odbc.ffdf(x = ff::as.ffdf.data.frame(dat), tablename = 
   tablename, odbcConnect.args = list(dsn = table, uid = "uid", pwd = 
    "***"))
```

}

```
writeTableSql("DDBBname", my_df, "table_name")
```

While it is working it stops and in the console says :

```
Browse [1] <
```

Any guess what could be the issue?

Comment: Looks sort of like one of the functions being called had a `browser()` line added to it for debugging purposes. Did you do that and forget to remove it?

Comment: @joran no, I haven't. How do I remove it?

Comment: The only time I've ever seen that prompt is if some code that's being run includes a call to `browser()`. It should say right above it "Called from: some_function()" which will tell you where it's coming from.

Comment: It is not like that @joran, the function works properly showing that is working and then from nowhere froze and popups that message not saying where it comes from.

Comment: In that case you'll need to provide something reproducible; without more information it's impossible to know what's going on.

Comment: You could also type `where` at the browser prompt and it should tell you what function calls are active.

Comment: The result of where is = where 8: do.call("sqlSave", sqlSave.args)
where 9 at #7: ETLUtils::write.odbc.ffdf(x = ff::as.ffdf.data.frame(dat), tablename = tablename, 
    odbcConnect.args = list(dsn = table, uid = "uid", pwd = "***"))
where 10: writeTableSql("Asig", iris, "iris_sql")